# MySQL removing NULL value from GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, null, pymysql

I know this question has been asked several times, but I could not get the answer.

I have a database with a table 'toronto', where all the amenities (e.g. restaurant) are mentioned, along with names of some of the amenities (e.g. Swiss Chalet). I want to group all the restaurants by unique names, and arrange them in descending order. However, even after using `IS NOT NULL` and `IFNULL`, I am not able to remove the NULL values.

I am using the following query:

```
query = '''SELECT `name`, COUNT( `name`) AS Amen  FROM `toronto` WHERE `name` IS NOT NULL and `amenity` like `restaurant` GROUP BY IFNULL(`name`,0) ORDER BY Amen DESC LIMIT 5;'''
cursor.execute (query)
```

And am getting the following result:

```
(('Swiss Chalet', 56), ('', 52), ('Sunset Grill', 30), ('Boston Pizza', 25), ("Wimpy's Diner", 17))
```

How do I remove the second result, which is a group of all NULL values in 'name' column? TIA

ps: I am using pymysql to query DB

Comment: using mysql 5.6 i believe :)

Comment: why are you using `LIKE` on amenity field if you are not using any wildcard?

Comment: @LelioFaieta I copied it from a bigger query to stress on the main issue. Thanks for pointing it out. I am actually using an array of amenities.. and then querying them on data parsed from Open Street Map. So it can be restaurant or restaurants :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a `null` value. It is a blank value, so you should add:

```
... WHERE `name` IS NOT NULL and name != ''...
```